c# handle large number of tcp connections
I created the following simple tcp listener, but when I load the test using Apache JMeter and 500 thread, I see a 0.5% error rate. How I can improve it?
How to find the reason error rate?
From Apache Jmeter I see the following error:
Response code: 500
Response message:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            int port = 7777;

            // Create a TCP listener
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started. Waiting for connections...");

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                

                    // Handle the client asynchronously
                    _ = HandleClientAsync(client);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }
      

        static async Task HandleClientAsync(TcpClient client)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string requestMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
               // Console.WriteLine("Request message from client: " + requestMessage);
    
                // Response message
                byte[] responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test response");

                //Thread.Sleep(50);
                // Send the response to the client asynchronously
                await stream.WriteAsync(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
                //Console.WriteLine("Response sent to client.");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the connection
                client.Close();
                //Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
            }

        }



You need to hand off the client to another task _ = Task.Run(() => HandleClientAsync(client)); otherwise it blocks other clients until the first one is done. There is also going to be a maximum number of sockets you can have open from one IP address. Why are you building your own TCP listener anyway, why not use a ready built one such as ASP.NET?

@Charlieface I have a old system, and want to improve system without significant changes, yes after Task.Run error rate decreased to 0.2%,  how to improve more?

ASP.NET Core handles far more connections than this. It does so by handing requests to threadpool threads for processing.

I have a old system how old? Although the problem seems to be the unusual coding, not the age. No matter how far back you go, this is simply wrong code - Encoding.ASCII  is the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding, not the UTF-8 used by most sites. A request can easily specify a different encoding in an HTTP header and the server has to respect it

without significant changes you'll probably have to make fewer changes if you switch to Minimal APIs than if you try to write your own concurrency and HTTP processing code. The quickstart example does with a single line a lot more than all this code, using less memory. Your code caches the entire request multiple times, in buffer and requestmessage. ASP.NET Core decodes bytes and processes them using reusable buffers, thus avoiding extra buffers

You need to hand off the client to another task otherwise it blocks other clients until the first await that actually runs asynchronously is hit.
_ = Task.Run(() => HandleClientAsync(client)); 

Any further improvement is going to be marginal: it's expected that a certain amount of TCP connections can fail when load-testing, that's how the testing knows when to back off.

Why would it block, it is not awaited.

It blocks until the first await that actually runs asynchronously.

But that is when reading of the stream begins.
